# Is there an alternative to Windows 8.1 SettingsFlyout in Windows 10 UWP development?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, appsettings, flyout

I'm currently developing a Windows 10 UWP application. Before I upgraded to Windows 10 I used the SettingsFlyout class in Windows 8.1. Now I red on stackoverflow that this class isn't supported by Windows 10.

So is there a good alternative for the flyout in Windows 10 UWP which has the same or similar handling?

Comment: The alternative would be to use a `SplitView` instead.

Comment: So I found out now that only the SettingsPane isn't working in my solution. The flyout is now working. If I use it like before and it isn't officialy supported by Microsoft, is there a problem with publishing the app on the Windows Store?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace Settings Flyout then there are some possible ways
**1. Add SettingsPage.xaml page with settings and navigation from AppBar:**

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsOpen="False" ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
<AppBarButton x:Name="btnSettings" Label="Settings" Click="btnSettings_Click" Icon="Setting"  >
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

And realize click event:

```
 private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
    }
```

But in this case it's better to add Back button.
At the end of OnLaunched event add:

```
rootFrame.Navigated += OnNavigated;
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
```

And add:

```
   private void OnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
 SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
        ((Frame)sender).CanGoBack ? AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible : AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

**2. Also add xaml page with settings, but use navigation with SplitView control and create Hamburger menu**

[Windows 10 SplitView – Build Your First Hamburger Menu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/quick_thoughts/2015/06/01/windows-10-splitview-build-your-first-hamburger-menu/)
[Implementing a Simple Hamburger Navigation Menu](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-021-Implementing-a-Simple-Hamburger-Navigation-Menu)

**3. Move settings to [ContentDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx)**

**4. If you don't have much settings you can put them into Flyout control**

```
<Button Content="Settings">
<Button.Flyout>
<MenuFlyout>
<ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Toggle Setting" />
<MenuFlyoutSeparator />
<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Setting 1" />
<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Setting 2" />
<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Setting 3" />
</MenuFlyout>
</Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```